# Non-linear ODE for double valued $y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What nice substitution can solve

$$ y ^{'2}(x)= y/a-b/y ; \,  BC: \quad y (\sqrt{ab})=0 $$

Hope its solution would be interesting.

Comment: Should the boundary condition be $y(\sqrt{ab}) = 0$ (instead of your current version: $y'(\sqrt{ab}) = 0$)?

Comment: I should solve for $x'(y)$ and integrate. The problem (to me) is that we shall arrive to some elliptic integrals.

Comment: can the elliptic integrals be cast into standard forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $$y'^2=\frac y a - \frac b y$$ we can rewrite $$x'=\pm \sqrt{\frac{a y}{y^2-a b}}$$ Changing variable $y=-\sqrt{a b} \sin (t)$, and assuming $a>0$, $b>0$, this write
$$x'=\pm \sqrt[4]\frac a b\cos (t) \sqrt{\tan (t) \sec (t)}$$ and, given by a CAS, $$\int\cos (t) \sqrt{\tan (t) \sec (t)}\,dt=-\frac{2 \cos (t) \sqrt{\tan (t)
   \sec (t)}}{\sqrt{\sin (t)}} E\left(\left.\frac{1}{4} (\pi -2 t)\right|2\right)$$ where appears the elliptic integral of the second kind

Comment: If possible please upload a graph for unequal values of $,a,b$

Comment: @Narasimham. First of all, I am unable to provide any graph : being almost blind, I do not "see" what I produce ! Second, you have the answer as a function of $t$ which just needs to be multiplied by $\pm \sqrt[4]\frac a b$.